# Reading numbers through serial communication on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, readline, strip, serial-communication

I have been trying to write a program that allows my Raspberry Pi to receive numbers through serial communication. I am communicating these numbers to the Raspberry Pi using an Arduino. The Arduino serial prints a prefix character followed by the number: `Serial.println("T"); Serial.println(483);` In the program, I am able to identify the prefix, but when I try to read the following number I am only able to get the first digit:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout = 0)

while True:
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        # If there's more than 20 bytes in the buffer, clear it.
        if ser.in_waiting >= 20:
            ser.reset_input_buffer()
        temp = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
        # Check to see what the prefix of the data is
        if (temp.strip().isalpha()):
            # If we got a 'T', it's a temperature update. Save temperature as number and print
            if (temp.strip() == 'T'):
                temp = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
                if temp.strip().isdigit():
                    number = (temp.strip())
                    print(number)
```

In this case, when I `print(number)` it outputs the number 4 and not 483. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Software with substitutions:

```
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        # If there's more than 20 bytes in the buffer, clear it.
        if ser.in_waiting >= 20:
            ser.reset_input_buffer()
        temp = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
        # Check to see what the prefix of the data is
        if (temp.strip().isalpha()):
            # If we got a 'T', it's a temperature update. Update the temperature
            if (temp.strip() == 'B'):
                b = ser.readline()
                print([int(c) for c in b])
                temp = b.decode('utf-8')
                if temp.strip().isdigit():
                    number = (temp.strip())
                    print ("temp = " + temp)
```

Output after `Serial.println("T"); Serial.println(483);` ran three times:

```
[52]
temp = 4
[]
[]
[]
[]
[52]
temp = 4
[52]
temp = 4
```

Comment: I think we need some more debugging information. Can you add: `print(temp)` after each `temp = ser.read...` line and report the output?

Comment: @quamrana When I remove ```print(number)``` and add ```print(temp)``` after each ```temp = ser.read...``` The program outputs this: ```B

4
83

B


483


B


483


B



483


B



48
3```                                                                                                    I had the Arduino ```Serial.println("T"); Serial.println(483);``` five times.

Comment: The baud rate of the Arduino and the Raspberry Pi are both set to 9600.

Comment: Its very odd that you see `B`, but you say that the program must be detecting `T` to be able to get to `print(number)` where you see just `4` printed.

Comment: @quamrana I completely forgot to mention, I changed the prefix to B. Sorry for the confusion. The same thing happens regardless of the prefix.

Comment: Ok, then further debug. Can you substitute in: `b = ser.readline() ; print([int(c) for c in b]); temp = b.decode('utf-8')` and see what is printed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242690/discussion-between-leng1-and-quamrana).

Comment: @quamrana I added the substitutions with the new output to the original post so it's easier to read.

Comment: Can you change your Arduino code: Serial.println("483")